# Delay loading of file constants based on script loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a file say constants.ts which contains hundreds of string constants exported and used in multiple files within app. I am looking to assign a value to them using a map loaded at runtime.

for example:
maper.js

```
exports.mapper= {
    "success": "success message...",
    "failure ": "failure message..."
};
```

file constant.ts

```
export const SUCCESS = (use_dynamic_strings)?(mapper.success):'ALL SET. Done'
export const FAILIURE = (use_dynamic_strings)?(mapper.failure):'SOMETHING BROKE. Not Done'
```

file app.ts

```
import * from './constants.ts'

function async onLoadAsync(): Promise<void>
{
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = './mapper.js';
  const loadPromise: Promise<void> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    script.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    };

  document.head.appendChild(script);
  return loadPromise;
}

REST OF CODE.....
```

Is there a way to delay the load of strings or assign them values only after execution of script load.??

Thanks in advance.